# How do I share files on Ubuntu using High Speed File share Cable

Tags: networking, file-sharing

I recently purchased a Targus high speed file sharing cable so i can transfer files from Windows Xp to Ubuntu back and forth, AKA Computer to computer connection. 
The easysuite software which is equipped in this device opens up on the xp but it dosnt support ubuntu (linux). Has anyone tryed this, and is their a linux driver or patch made up that i can install on Ubuntu that will also work with this device?

cheers.